# In React, how do I apply Block Display style to each item produced by .map, instead of entire Component produced by .map?

Tags: css, reactjs, array.prototype.map

My goal is to display different numbers of text inputs using the .map method. I want them to display stacked on top of each other (block), but my CSS rule for it I believe applies to the whole component, instead of each text input within the component. How do I make the text inputs display as stacked?

Here is the code to set up the text inputs:

```
export default function App() {
  const [textInputs, setTextInputs] = useState({});
  // User this state variable to dynamically set amount of lines
  const [numLines, setNumLines] = useState(6);
```

Here is the return value:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <h1 className="tool-textheader">write...</h1>
      <div className="tool-container">
        {[...Array(numLines).keys()].map((i) => {
          return (
            <div key={`tool${i}`} className="tool-item">
              <input
                className="input-lines"
                type="text-area"
                value={textInputs[`input${i}`]}
                onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value, i)}
              />)
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.input-lines {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure where you're going wrong but your code works according to the description ; https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-meninsky-0618m4?file=/src/App.js . I'm going to guess that maybe your className="tool-container" has as property of flex that might be changing them to in-line

Comment: Hmmm, it's still not working in my own project, so the fact that the sandbox works means that there must be something somewhere in the rest of my code overriding it or messing it up. Thank you for providing this insight!

Comment: Open the chrome dev tools  and inspect the elements. Specifically the parent div . You might have some styles there

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the element within a parent node component. Give the parent display: flex  and you should be good to go. May need to change the flex-direction depending on usage.